# Migrated CF2016 to CF2018 and a remote jquery ajax call is now failing

Tags: coldfusion, jquery-validate

We have a CFC set for remote access.  When we were on CF2016 returntype="any" or returntype="string" with returnformat="plain" worked fine with jqueryvalidate when checking if a username was in use or not.  Now, if the username is in use we correctly get an error message stating that.  However, when the username is available, it validates as not valid and passes the CFC's response ("TRUE") through to the browser as the error message.  From the documentation, it's not seeing the response as a json true:

> The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be "true" for valid elements, and can be "false", undefined, or null for invalid elements, using the default error message. If the serverside response is a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead", this string will be displayed as a custom error message in place of the default.

I've tried changing the CFC to returntype="json", as well as adding serializeJSON() to the returned data and what should validate as an available username just shows "TRUE" and thus fails validation.

Comment: Does the server return `"TRUE"`, `TRUE`, or `true`? Only `true` is a valid JSON boolean.

Comment: TRUE or "TRUE".  Will have to research more tomorrow.

Comment: I helped write this part of the documentation.  The plugin works when a string is echo'd back.  `"true"` should work and `"true"` does not need to be JSON encoded.  In other words, for PHP, `echo "true"` works the same as `echo json_encode("true")`.  I don't know what the corresponding code would be in ColdFusion.

Comment: Show the actual code.  You `echo` the response, not `return`.  The response is a JSON encoded string.